# Is there a way using VBscript to check if PS2 keyboard and/or PS2 mouse are attached to a computer running Windows XP or above?

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I've a pretty complicated quetions for the community:
I have to manage a lab with hundreds of PCs running Win XP Pro SP3. Sometimes students disconnect keyboards and/or mouses from computers so after every class I've to check every single machine and check if they are atteched and this steal me a lot o time. So I'm writing a script in VBScript for checking machines and put infos about configuration into a database that helps me telling if there is something wrong on a machine. Now, I'd like to check, also, if PS2 keyboard and/or PS2 mouse are attached or not so I can immediately restoring them before a new class starts without goin' for attempt, machine by machine. How can I achive this? WMI? How? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394582) should probably be able to provide this information. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475187/detecting-ps-2-port-state-in-c-sharp) for examples. You will probably [need](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/30/use-powershell-and-wmi-to-find-wireless-keyboard-amp-mouse.aspx) `Win32_Keyboard` and `Win32_PointingDevice`, maybe `Win32_PnPEntity` if those [do not report disconnecting](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/f1dac890-0572-4a3c-8b4d-2d4da19af373/monitoring-disconnected-status-of-ps2-keyboard-and-desktop-monitor#0dfceb31-a1f4-42ec-b295-57dfb95fea61) (I cannot test PS/2 hardware).

All this should translate into VBScript, maybe using Microsoft's [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.11.heyscriptingguy.aspx) about [WMI from VBScript](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12028). For a start:

```
On Error Resume Next
For Each strComputer In Array("localhost")
  WScript.Echo "Computer: " & strComputer
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
  Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Keyboard", "WQL", &h30)
  For Each objItem In colItems
    WScript.Echo objItem.Availability, objItem.Caption, _
      objItem.ConfigManagerErrorCode, objItem.ConfigManagerUserConfig, _
      objItem.Description, objItem.DeviceID, _
      objItem.ErrorCleared, objItem.ErrorDescription, _
      objItem.IsLocked, _
      objItem.LastErrorCode, _
      objItem.Layout, _
      objItem.Name, _
      objItem.PNPDeviceID, _
      objItem.Status, objItem.StatusInfo, _
      objItem.SystemCreationClassName, objItem.SystemName
  Next
  Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PointingDevice", "WQL", &h30)
  For Each objItem In colItems
    WScript.Echo objItem.Availability, objItem.Caption, _
      objItem.ConfigManagerErrorCode, objItem.ConfigManagerUserConfig, _
      objItem.Description, objItem.DeviceID, _
      objItem.DeviceInterface, _
      objItem.ErrorCleared, objItem.ErrorDescription, _
      objItem.HardwareType, _
      objItem.IsLocked, _
      objItem.LastErrorCode, _
      objItem.Name, _
      objItem.PNPDeviceID, _
      objItem.PointingType, _
      objItem.Status, objItem.StatusInfo, _
      objItem.Synch, _
      objItem.SystemCreationClassName, objItem.SystemName
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Many many thanks Michel! It seems working perfectly! I tried on a machine: one time with keyboard and mouse plugged in and I got two msgboxes (one with keyboard data and one with mouse data); one time just with keyboard and I got only the msgbox with keyboard data; one time just with mouse plugged in and I got only the msgbox with mouse data. Thanks again!